# Latest Stable offset in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, librdkafka

I have a producer application where I use both transactional and non-transactional producer to send messages to a partition in Kafka. I had a requirement where I want to fetch Latest Stable Offset from Kafka and send to some database.

I have built my producer application using librdkafka library but I didn't find any suitable function to get Latest Stable Offset.

Any suggestions to solve this issue.